# Images align in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I am creating a website and would like a little help to align my images like this

[image]

and here is my code, but I have not had the desired result

```
    <img height="632" width="428" src="img/default.png" class="pull-left">

            <div>
                <img height="318" width="221" src="img/default.png">

                <img height="318" width="221" src="img/default.png">



                <img height="318" width="221" src="img/default.png">

                <img height="318" width="221" src="img/default.png">
            </div> <img height="632" width="428" src="img/default.png" class="pull-right">
```

don't blame me , I'm a beginner :p and thank's for your help ( I can use Bootstrap )

Comment: Make a table with hidden borders.
So are you trying to learn html or are you aiming to make a website?
Bootstrap is definitely the way to go for the latter due to smaller screen etc, but for the former doing a table in html is the way.

Comment: Actually, at 428+221+221+428≈1,200. where you planning on having it as %? If you don't want your images squished you can omit height. and then convert the widths to %.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and insert images into cells:

```
    <table border="1"> 
    <!--First row -->
    <tr> 
    <td rowspan="2" width="428" height="632"> 632*428 </td>
    <td width="221" height="318"> 318*221 </td>
    <td width="221" height="318"> 318*221 </td>
    <td rowspan="2" width="428" height="632"> 632*428 </td>
    </tr>
    <!--Second row -->
    <tr>
    <td width="221" height="318"> 318*221 </td>
    <td width="221" height="318"> 318*221 </td>
    </tr> 
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the following DOM:

```
 <div style="display:flex">
   <img height="632" width="221" src="img/default.png">
    <div>
      <div><img height="318" width="221" src="img/default.png"></div>
      <div><img height="318" width="221" src="img/default.png"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
     <div><img height="318" width="221" src="img/default.png"></div>
     <div><img height="318" width="221" src="img/default.png"></div>
   </div>
  <img height="632" width="221" src="img/default.png">
</div>
```

In addition I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oronbdd/cL4rkfab/) for you :)